# Reordenar sequencia numérica ao alterar posição do array

Tags: c#

Tenho uma lista de categoria financeiras

Minha model

```
public class Categoria 
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public string Nome {get;set;}
   public int Sequencia {get;set;}
}
```

E conforme às move para cima e para baixo é necessário atualizar a propriedade Sequencia

```
var oldIndex = categoria.Sequencia;
var newIndex = categoria.Sequencia + 1 //Para cima
var newIndex = categoria.Sequencia - 1 //Para baixo
```

Mas não faço ideia de como reordenar o campo Sequencia atualizando seus códigos

Exemplo, lista inicial:

```
1 - ÁGUA
2 - LUZ,
3 - Internet
```

Você dar um `Up` da Internet, então deve atualizar e ficar na seguinte sequência

```
1 - ÁGUA
2 - Internet
3 - Luz
```

O que tentei até o momento:

```
    var categoria = await db.categorias.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    var categorias = await db.categorias.ToListAsync();

    var oldIndex = categoria.Sequencia;
    var newIndex = direcao == "UP" ? categoria.Sequencia + 1 : categoria.Sequencia - 1;

    foreach (var cat in categorias.Where(x => x.Sequencia > newIndex && x.Sequencia <= oldIndex && x.Id != categoria.Id))
    {
        cat.Sequencia = cat.Sequencia --;
    }
    category.Sequencia = newIndex;
```

Comment: Desculpa, não consegui entender a sua dúvida

Comment: @LeandroAngelo seria para reordenar o indice quando for passado Up ou Down

Comment: Mas se o usuário clicar 10 vezes seguidas no up ou down, você vai fazer esse processo de ir no banco 20 vezes (visto que você vai duas vezes no banco nesse código atual, 2 vezes * 10 cliques = 20) para atualizar a ordenação? Talvez poderia mudar o fluxo para ele ordenar tudo, clicando em up ou down (mas ainda não aplica a atualização no banco de dados) e quando o usuário clicar em um botão para aplicar a ordenação, somente nesse caso você realiza as modificações no banco de dados. O que acha?

Comment: @PedroPaulo a lista normalmente não passa dos 30 itens, mesmo buscando todas as horas fica com uma UX/UI mais acessível para o usuário entender

Answer (score 1):

Conforme eu falei nos comentários, diria para avaliar uma forma melhor de fazer isso, pois se o usuário clicar várias vezes no botão, são várias chamadas ao banco de dados. Não consigo sugerir algo melhor aqui por mensagem e sem ver o seu cenário de UI, mas com certeza existe uma maneira mais eficiente de se fazer isso.

Porém vou tentar lhe ajudar no seu cenário atual.

```
var categoriaModificada1 = await db.categorias.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

if (categoriaModificada1 != null)
{
    var novaSequencia = direcao == "UP" ? categoriaModificada1.Index - 1 : categoriaModificada1.Index + 1;
    var categoriaModificada2 = await db.categorias.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Index == novaSequencia);

    if (categoriaModificada2 != null)
    {
        categoriaModificada2.Index = categoriaModificada1.Index;
        categoriaModificada1.Index = novaSequencia;
        db.SaveChanges();            
    }
}
```

Fiz esse trecho de código baseado no seu cenário atual e no seu exemplo acima:

> ```
> 1 - ÁGUA
> 2 - LUZ,
> 3 - Internet
> ```
>
> Você dar um Up da Internet, então deve atualizar e ficar na seguinte
> sequência
>
> ```
> 1 - ÁGUA
> 2 - Internet
> 3 - Luz
> ```

Comment: Obrigado Pedro, mas e se for de forma recursiva?

Comment: Não entendi. O que seria de forma recursiva? Essa forma que está feita, é para o seu cenário, quando o usuário clica para cima ou para baixo, vai mudar a ordenação dos 2 itens. Esse código funciona para cada clique.

Comment: Pedro, a sua solução é somente para organizar 2 dos itens, e esses itens são dinamicos, podem ter 2 ou 50 por exemplo rsrs

Comment: Sim, pois pelo o que entendi, você chama o backend a cada clique do usuário no UI, então sempre irá reordenar 2 itens. Quando o usuário clica para cima ou para baixo, somente 2 itens estão sendo alterados. Se ele clicar 2 vezes, você vai chamar esse método acima 2 vezes, assim irá ajustar corretamente. Foi isso que eu sugeri arrumar anteriormente... Arrumar uma solução para fazer apenas uma vez, mas isso tem que analisar o projeto e não consigo fazer aqui somente com um exemplo, preciso entender a tela onde isso se aplica.